# jquery inside $.each (function) want create variables and then use the variables outside function

Tags: jquery

Here is example http://jsfiddle.net/gtrk77ro/5/

Inside function `$.each(address, function(index, item) {` I define variables `latitude` and `longitude`.

And later, after the function want to alert (keep) the values.

Expect `alert( latitude + ' latitude expect alert last' );` to alert after `alert( latitude + ' latitude expect alert first' );`, but it alerts first and value is `null`.

What need to correct?

Here is the code

```
var latitude = null;
var longitude = null;

$(function() {

var address = [ "Collins+Street,+MELBOURNE,+VIC,+AUSTRALIA,+3000", "Sussex+Street,+SYDNEY,+NSW,+AUSTRALIA,+2000", "George+Street,+BRISBANE,+QLD,+AUSTRALIA,+4000"];

$.each(address, function(index, item) {
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

geocoder.geocode( { 'address': item}, function(results, status) {

if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
}

alert( latitude + ' latitude expect alert first' );

});//geocoder.geocode

});//$.each(address, function(index, item) {

alert( latitude + ' latitude expect alert last' );

});

alert( latitude + ' latitude expect alert last outside function' );
```

Comment: that smelly smell of ajax...

Comment: just a sidenote advice, use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`. much more convenient and aesthetic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70471/discussion-between-amit-joki-and-banana).

Comment: the call to geocoder is asynchronous. You can't access the data until it has returned. Do whatever you need to inside the callback. Not sure what you are trying to do in the first place,